# URL Shortener Spam

Tags: asp-classic, spam-prevention

Lately I'm starting to receive spam URLs into my forum software via URL shortener. In the past, they are easy to block by domain, but I can't exactly block the domain for URL shortener since I'm seeing some valid usage as well.

Any best practice on how to manage these spam URLs (and spammers that are using it)?

Comment: How do you characterize a URL as spam URL and what’s wrong with spam URLs?

Comment: The URLs come from several blacklisted domains (which now instead of the original domain it is being displayed as the URL shortener domain). What's wrong with blocking spam URLs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also do something like http://www.untiny.me/ when a post is submitted. Basically, send an HTTP request and capture the "HTTP 301" response. You can then examine the URL you're being redirected to and deny/allow based on your policy.

For example:

```
C:\>wget -O NUL http://tiny.pl/htk
--2011-01-24 21:47:33--  http://tiny.pl/htk
Resolving tiny.pl... 79.96.141.187
Connecting to tiny.pl|79.96.141.187|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301           <====
Location: http://www.google.com [following]           <====
--2011-01-24 21:47:34--  http://www.google.com/
```

Relevant lines marked by `<====`

Comment: Interesting idea. Will try implementing later.

Answer (score 3):

Some form of [CAPCHA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capcha) might be a good idea. If you required registration prior to allowing a user to post, stick it in your registration form. Otherwise, maybe stick it wherever the user posts from as a requirement prior to accepting a post.

Comment: These are manual submission by a person. CAPTCHA doesn't solve this problem.