# Typical URL lengths for storage calculation purposes (URL-shortener)

Tags: php, mysql, url, storage

After reading several of the hits on a quick [google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=average%20url%20length), it seems there is not a whole lot of consistency when it comes to determining average URL length.

I know IE has a maximum URL length of 2083 characters (from [here](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=121352)) - so I have a good maximum to work with.

My concern is that I am writing a URL-shortener in PHP ([similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066601/developing-a-url-shortener) to some other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789454/url-shortener-spam) on SO), and want to make sure I am not likely to exceed the storage capability of the server hosting it.

If all URLs are the IE maximum, then `2^32` won't fit comfortably anywhere - it'd take `2K x 4B ~= 8TB` of storage: an unrealistic expectation.

Without adding-in a trimming function (ie, purging "old" shortened URLs), what is the *safest* way to calculate storage usage of the app?

Is ~34 [characters](http://www.supermind.org/blog/559/average-length-of-a-url) a safe guess? If so, then a fully-populated (using an `int` type for a primary key) database would chew 292GB of space (double 146GB for any meta data that may want to be stored).

What is the best-guess for an application such as this?

Comment: You want to store 2 billion urls?

Comment: @Ted Hopp - I'm looking at worst-case maxima, not what I truly anticipate

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is probably unknowable without indexing the entire Internet, but according to an analysis by Kelvin Tan on [a dataset of 6,627,999 unique URLs from 78,764 unique domains](http://www.supermind.org/blog/740/average-length-of-a-url-part-2), the answer is **76.97**:

> **Mean:** 76.97
>
> **Standard Deviation:** 37.41
>
> **95th% confidence interval:** 157
>
> **99.5th% confidence interval:** 218

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure what is typical, but of 11,000 urls in our request database, the average length is 62 characters. There are hundreds of urls with several hundred characters. The longest is a Google Translate link at 1689 characters.

```
top 10 len(producturl):
1689
792
707
693
647
606
574
569
562
560
```

sample url 647 characters:

> http://www.amazon.co.jp/%E9%AD%94%E7%95%8C%E6%88%A6%E8%A8%98%E3%83%87%E3%82%A3%E3%82%B9%E3%82%AC%E3%82%A4%E3%82%A24-%E5%88%9D%E5%9B%9E%E9%99%90%E5%AE%9A%E7%89%88-%E5%A0%95%E5%A4%A9%E4%BD%BF%E3%83%95%E3%83%AD%E3%83%B3-%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%83%80%E3%82%AF%E3%83%88%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E4%BB%98%E3%81%8D%E7%89%B9%E8%A3%BD%E3%82%AB%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89-%E3%83%88%E3%83%AC%E3%83%BC%E3%83%87%E3%82%A3%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0%E3%82%AB%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%80%8C%E3%83%B4%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%82%B9%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A5%E3%83%B4%E3%82%A1%E3%83%AB%E3%83%84%E3%80%8D%E9%99%90%E5%AE%9APR%E3%82%AB%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E4%BB%98%E3%81%8D/dp/B0043RT8UO/ref=pd_rhf_p_t_1

P.S. for estimating purposes you should extrapolate from some dataset after applying standard deviation to throw out the outliers which could distort your mean.

Answer (score 2):

From [RFC 2068](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2068.txt) section 3.2.1:

> The HTTP protocol does not place any a priori limit on the length of
>      a URI. Servers MUST be able to handle the URI of any resource they
>      serve, and SHOULD be able to handle URIs of unbounded length if they
>      provide GET-based forms that could generate such URIs. A server
>      SHOULD return 414 (Request-URI Too Long) status if a URI is longer
>      than the server can handle (see section 10.4.15).
>
> Note: Servers should be cautious about depending on URI lengths
>        above 255 bytes, because some older client or proxy implementations
>        may not properly support these lengths.

Although IE (and probably most other browsers) support much longer URI lengths, I don't believe most forms or client-side apps rely on anything above 255 bytes working. Your server logs should provide some statistics about what kind of urls you are seeing.

Comment: I think it’s rather the target URL length he is worrying about.

Comment: Well, yes, but who generates the target URL? Typically, long URLs come from links generated by web apps, or by url-encoded form submissions, javascript, or other client-side code.

Comment: But how should observing the server’s logs solve this? I don’t think he wants to shorten his own server’s URLs.

Comment: I have no idea what he wants to shorten. I just suggested that as a way to collect raw data about url/uri lengths. But you're right, it might be data that is irrelevant to what he's trying to do.